# why my uitableview cell row is repeating subtitles

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my uitableview I have two sections

first is fetched from core data

other is added through textfield which is stored in NSMutableArray(otherFriends)

here is my code

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if([otherFriends count]>0)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)sectionIndex
{
    if(otherFriends == 0)
    {
        return [[[[self fetchedResultsController]sections]objectAtIndex:0]numberOfObjects];
    }
    return [otherFriends count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"newGroupCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Light" size:20.0];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.0f];

    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        user = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.textLabel.text = user.name;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = user.primaryResource.status;

        [cell.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
        [cell.imageView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

        if (user.photo != nil)
        {
            cell.imageView.image = user.photo;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultPerson"];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [otherFriends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultPerson"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

First section also have subtitles but second section cells have no subtitles

when I am adding new friend it works fine till all rows are visible, but when adding new friend and that row is not visible and to view that row I must scroll, then this row show the subtitle of first row in section 0(the very first cell) and its repeating in section 1 third row. Only subtitle is repeating but the main text is not.

For several hours I am trying to figure out this but no luck.

Comment: The edit shows a problem unrelated to the original issue. Consider rolling back the edit and writing a separate question about programmatic selection of rows. I can tell you right away that the way you do it is absolutely incorrect. I am reluctant to write up an answer, though, because it is totally unrelated to your original question. Make a new question, call it "How do you select UITableView rows programmatically", and paste your second code snippet.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Please view my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411249/how-do-you-select-uitableview-rows-programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in your `else` branch you are not setting the `cell.detailTextLabel.text`.

When a cell gets recycled, the old detailTextLabel stays there. You need to set all properties of the cell in both branches of the conditionsl, on the chance that it has been recycled.

```
if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
    user = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = user.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = user.primaryResource.status;

    [cell.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    [cell.imageView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    if (user.photo != nil)
    {
        cell.imageView.image = user.photo;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultPerson"];
    }
}
else
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [otherFriends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultPerson"];
    // ADDED
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
    // You may also need to adjust the frame of the cell.imageView
    // because it could have been recycled.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying ... I have another issue that now I have to provide a select deselect option similar to email selection and user can also select deselect random rows. This is also creating problem that checkmark are also not displaying properly.

Comment: @S.J You have to do pretty much the same thing with the accessory view of the cell: no matter what path you take through the code of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, all elements of the cell must be written to. In other words, if you write it once, you must write to it every time, no matter what branch of the `if` you take.

Answer (score 0):

Cells get reused. Since you are using the same cells for both sections, you must be sure to set/reset the same set of cell properties in all conditions.

The problem is when the cell is used for section 1, you don't reset the `detailTextLabel`. In your `else` block, add:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;
```

This ensures that in all cases you are setting the `textLabel`, `detailTextLabel`, and the `imageView` properties for the reused cells.