# How do you select uitableview rows programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am trying to achive a email like select all functionality in uitableview where on same button tap user can checkmark or remove all checkmark and additionally user can also select/deselect rows(on didSelectRowAtIndexPath). I tried to do but its not working properly,  here is my code.

```
- (IBAction)selectAll:(id)sender
{
    if(myBoolean)
    {
        for (NSInteger s = 0; s < self.iTable.numberOfSections; s++)
        {
            for (NSInteger r = 0; r < [self.iTable numberOfRowsInSection:s]; r++)
            {
                [[self.iTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:r inSection:s]] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
            }
        }

        myBoolean = NO;

        [_selectUnselectButton setTitle:@"Select all Friends" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        for (NSInteger s = 0; s < self.iTable.numberOfSections; s++)
        {
            for (NSInteger r = 0; r < [self.iTable numberOfRowsInSection:s]; r++)
            {
                [[self.iTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:r inSection:s]] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
                NSLog(@"%d-%d",s,r);
            }
        }

        myBoolean = YES;

        [_selectUnselectButton setTitle:@"Unselect all Friends" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView_ didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView_ cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the actual problem? Is it happens when you scrolling the tableview after checkmarking some items....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the accessory view needs to happen *inside* the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. When you want to change the accessories from outside, the outside method needs to change the model first to indicate that check marks must be placed in certain cells, and then call `reloadData` on the `UITableView`.

One way to store what cells are checked is an array of `NSIndexSet` objects - one index set per section. In the example below I show code for a single section, but you should get an idea of how to make multiple sections work.

```
// This variable needs to be declared in a place where your data source can get it
NSMutableIndexSet *selected;

// You need to initialize it in the designated initializer, like this:
selected = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    if ([selected containsIndex:indexPath.row]) {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    } else {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }
    // Do the rest of your code
    return cell;
}
```

Now in the code where you want to set rows selected or unselected you just need to call `[selected addIndex:rowToSelect]` or `[selected removeIndex:rowToUnselect]`, and call your table's `reloadData`.

Comment: I could not understand what should I store in NSMutableIndexSet *selected; ,Because I tried to store int, NSInteger,NSUInteger ,Need help Thanks

Comment: @MacGeek You can't store any of these. You need to use `NSNumber` ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22187826/335858)).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, What Can I do If I want to get my checked cell(Cell AccessoryType) as per my JSON Result array? -PreChecked cell as per my given Index,Any idea?

Comment: @MacGeek I am not sure what you are trying to do. The best thing would be to post a new question with relevant code.

Answer (score 8):

I wrote a [sample code](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/checkmark/tree/master/Checkmark) that I adapted to your needs.

Basically it is

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *unifiedID = @"aCellID";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:unifiedID];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:unifiedID];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.states objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //if the indexPath was found among the selected ones, set the checkmark on the cell
    cell.accessoryType = ([self isRowSelectedOnTableView:tableView atIndexPath:indexPath]) ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    return cell;

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *state = [self.states objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if([self isRowSelectedOnTableView:tableView atIndexPath:indexPath]){
        [self.selectedCells removeObject:indexPath];
        [self.selecedStates removeObject:state];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    } else {
        [self.selectedCells addObject:indexPath];
        [self.selecedStates addObject:state];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", self.selecedStates);
}


-(BOOL)isRowSelectedOnTableView:(UITableView *)tableView atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return ([self.selectedCells containsObject:indexPath]) ? YES : NO;
}


- (IBAction)selectAll:(id)sender {

    [self.selecedStates removeAllObjects];
    [self.selectedCells removeAllObjects];
    NSUInteger numberOfSections = [self.tableView numberOfSections];
    for (NSUInteger s = 0; s < numberOfSections; ++s) {
        NSUInteger numberOfRowsInSection = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:s];
        for (NSUInteger r = 0; r < numberOfRowsInSection; ++r) {
            NSIndexPath *idxPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:r inSection:s];
            [self.selectedCells addObject:idxPath];
            [self.selecedStates addObject:self.states[idxPath.row]];
        }
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}



- (IBAction)deselectAll:(id)sender {
    [self.selecedStates removeAllObjects];
    [self.selectedCells removeAllObjects];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (IBAction)toggleAll:(id)sender {
    if ([self.states count] == [self.selecedStates count]) {
        [sender setTitle:@"select all"];
        [self deselectAll:sender];
    } else {
        [sender setTitle:@"deselect all"];
        [self selectAll:sender];
   }
}
```

in action:

### [image]

You are calling

```
[[self.iTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:r inSection:s]] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
```

for every row in every section within the tableView. if you have many row, this is ver inefficient, as it will deal with rows not on the screen. But this is not needed. just put every selected index path into an array and tell the tableView to reload. This will reload the visible cells and due to the implementation of `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` cells wfor new rows will be correctly re-conigured.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/selectRowAtIndexPath%3aanimated%3ascrollPosition%3a) to select a row
and [`deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/deselectRowAtIndexPath%3aanimated%3a) to deselect a row.
For more read the [UITableView docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code instead of your old one

```
- (IBAction)selectAll:(id)sender
{
    if(myBoolean)
    {
        for (NSInteger s = 0; s < self.iTable.numberOfSections; s++)
        {
            for (NSInteger r = 0; r < [self.iTable numberOfRowsInSection:s]; r++)
            {
              [self.iTable selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:r inSection:s]] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

            }
        }

        myBoolean = NO;

        [_selectUnselectButton setTitle:@"Select all Friends" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        for (NSInteger s = 0; s < self.iTable.numberOfSections; s++)
        {
            for (NSInteger r = 0; r < [self.iTable numberOfRowsInSection:s]; r++)
            {
                 [self.iTable selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:r inSection:s]] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
                NSLog(@"%d-%d",s,r);
            }
        }

        myBoolean = YES;

        [_selectUnselectButton setTitle:@"Unselect all Friends" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView_ didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView_ cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps to implement this,

1) You should have a `mutable` array to store indexpaths

2) What you can do is, when you tap Check All or Uncheck All, do `add` or `remove` all indexpaths to/from array (which you've), reload table for update changes

3) In `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` datasource method, check into array using `if([array containsObject:indexPath])`, if exist mark it `checked` or `unchecked`

4) In `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` delegate method, you should check for already existence of indexpath tapped into array, as you've did in 3rd step, and *add* or *remove* `indexpaths` as per the condition, reload table for update changes

Answer (score 0):

Take another `NSMutableArray` as **SelectedArray**

in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` row You can Add remove objects from **SelectedArray**.

You can select a `UITableViewCell` calling `UITableViews` `selectRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
[yourtable selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] 
                       animated:NO 
                 scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
```

Put for loop for **selectedArray** to putcheckmark only in selected cells or All cells.

check my accepted answer here : [Need to create a select all button for UITableView and add selections to an array in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209145/need-to-create-a-select-all-button-for-uitableview-and-add-selections-to-an-arra/14210436#14210436)

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 8x

Swift 3x

***Select Row***

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
mytableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .bottom)
myTableView.delegate?.tableView!(myTableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
```

***DeSelect Row***

```
let deselectIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 7, section: 0)
myTableView.deselectRow(at: deselectIndexPath, animated: true)
myTableView.delegate?.tableView!(tblView, didDeselectRowAt: indexPath)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self doSomethingWithRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: i guess the `doSomethingWithRowAtIndexPath:` is the more interesting part …