# UITableViewCell using checkmark as a toggle switch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to use the Checkmark as an toggle switch to let user selects a bundle of items, but this is not working as expected - I have to tap the cell 2 times for the cell to toggle checkmark on/off. And if I do `[tableView reloadData]` instead of `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` it does not work at all.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;        
    } else if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411249/how-do-you-select-uitableview-rows-programmatically/14411866#14411866

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is changing the view property and then reloading the table view from your model data. You should be changing the model data instead of the view property before you do the reload.